# How to create new list with name from element in other list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, widget, append

I wnat to use list name from element in other list, but occur the some error.
if there is `title_list = [A, B, C]`, I want to make list ex) `B.append(test_items)`

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry
import tkinter as tk

ent1_input = []
ent2_input = []
title_list = []
test_item_list = []
entry1 = 0
entry2 = 0

def addentry():
    ent1 = Entry(root)
    ent1.pack()
    ent1_input.append(ent1)

def click_B():
    global title

    for entry1 in ent1_input:
        title = entry1.get()
        create_window()
        title_list.append(title)

def create_window():

    def addBox2():
        ent2 = Entry(new_root)
        ent2.pack()
        ent2_input.append(ent2)

    def test_item_list_up():
        global test_items

        for i in range(0, len(title_list)):

            for entry2 in ent2_input:
                test_items = entry2.get()
                title_lsit[i].append(test_items) # <---- What do i change it

    new_root = tk.Tk()
    new_root.geometry('200x200')
    addboxButton = Button(new_root, text= title , command=addBox2)
    addboxButton.pack(side="top", expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)
    applyButton = Button(new_root, text="Apply value",command=test_item_list_up)
    applyButton.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.title('initialization')
root.configure(background='green')
b = Button(root, text="Set Items", command=addentry)
b.pack(side="top", expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)
c = Button(root, text="Apply Items", command=click_B)
c.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It is possible view some sample code, I've only been studying **Python** for weeks.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. please post only the relevant code where you think you're facing the issue. mention the input list and the output required.

Comment: lsit A = [abc, xyz, rgb]

I want to make a new list as below

list abc = [...]
list xyz = [...]
list rgb = [...]

I want to use the elements of existing lists as new names.

Comment: It sounds like are trying to take a string from a list, and use that string as the name of a new variable. Is that correct? If so, don't do that. Dynamically created variable names lead to very hard to understand and debug code, and provide no real value. Can you explain why you need to use data as variable names? What problem do you think that solves?

Comment: Your says is correct. I need to user input from first widget entry then make list with user input value. and make several widget with entry as much as user input quantity. and create some lists with second widget entry value. Entry quantity is variable as user,s wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not make a list like that. You can make a dictionary.

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a_dict = dict.fromkeys(a_list, list())
for k in a_dict:
    a_dict[k].append(test_items)
```

Comment: @Backjunee I thought there is a way to do this using eval() but I tried it and it gives me an error. Regardless, using eval() is frowned upon. This is the best way to do what I assume is dynamic list creation at runtime.

Comment: it's possible using `eval()`, but you're right about "frowned upon". However, [take a look](https://ideone.com/OMf7ak) if you curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot your advice, I try more thanx

Comment: @Backjunee if & when you decide this is the answer you were looking for then do click on the checkmark next to the answer and accept it.